# isn't big Oh asymptotic notation {O(f(n)}the slowest runtime an algorithm can have?(it gives asymptotic upper bound which means slowest runtime)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

i was reading a book called "Introduction to algorithms" and they were analyzing an algorithm called Strassen's algorithm for matrix multiplication and it said this-
""one might at first think that any matrix multiplication algorithm must take omega(n3)time, since the natural definition of matrix multiplication requires that many mul-tiplications. You would be incorrect, however: we have a way to multiply matrices in O(n3) time.""

isn't O(n3) time slower than omega(n3) time.
as omega gives asymtotic lower bound means fastest runtime.
than why the book say that we can do it in O(n3) like it is faster tha omega(n3) time.

Comment: No, big oh does *not* mean worst-case, nor does omega means best case. Both big oh and big omega can be used to describe best/average/worst time/memory/error progression/...

Comment: Big omega is however a "tight bound" in the time complexity class, whereas big oh is not. For example if an algorithm runs in *O(n^2)*, you can as well say it runs in *O(n^3)*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations

Comment: Try to think of big O and big Omega as "at most" and "at least", then it makes sense: "You might think this dinner might take at least $30, but we have a way to have this dinner in less than $30."

Comment: i know it does not mean best case or worse case and that runtime is generally different for different cases. i just want to know that isn't O(n) a poorer runtime{the poorest runtime for that case (best/average/worst)} than big omega(n){the best runtime an algo can have for that particular case.}

Comment: @ElProfessor: no, the idea of *O(...)* is that if you take a look at the definition of it, it makes it very easy to "over exaggerate". For example an algorithm that runs linear is *O(n)*, but it is *O(n^2)*, *O(2^n)*, etc. as well. Since all these function dominate *O(n)*. Big omega, means that if you take the limit, the limit is greater than zero, but still dominates, so that means that if an algorithm runs linear, you can not say it runs *Omega(n^2)*, since then the limit is 0, it is thus a "smaller" set of functions than big oh.

Comment: okay,thanks for helping me but i still have one  doubt.  if someone asks to rate T1(n)=omega(n),T2(n)=O(n),T3(n)=theta(n) {for the same problem for eg, a matrix multiplication problem} in increasing or decreasing order.  than what will be the answer or is it just a wrong question to ask.

Comment: @ElProfessor: you can not say what the best one will be, all possible orders (from best to worst) all possible.

Comment: You can think of it as such: O(n) means "at most linear" (could be less, even constant), Omega(n) means "at least linear" (could be exponential) and Theta(n) means "about linear" (3*n is an example, (1+0.5*cos(n))*n is another). So asymptotically, and ignoring constant factors, O(n) would be at most as slow as Omega(n) and Theta(n), Omega(n) is at least as slow as O(n) and Theta(n), Theta(n) is as least as slow as O(n) and at most as slow as Omega(n). See https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/asymptotic-notation/a/big-big-theta-notation for nice explanations.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is *not* true that, as people commonly seem to believe, Big-O is worst case, Big-Omega is best case, and Big-Theta is average case.

Big-O is an upper bound. We are often interested in an upper bound on the worst case so Big-O gets associated with worst case behavior, but we can also be interested in an upper bound on  average case behavior, etc.

When we are using asymptotic notation applied to running times, "higher" functions are worse so upper bounds are good. If the algorithm has an upper bound, O(n^3), time this is better than it having a lower bound, Ω(n^3), because a lower bound means that it could be worse, could be slower, that it is no better than the lower bound.